# Disabling Sunday on a date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am working on a website that delivers products. We can't deliver on a Sunday so I am trying to blank it out on the date picker calendar. Below is the code, would anyone be able to help where they can't choose Sunday delivery.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
    minDate: +1, 
    maxDate: "+3M"
  } );  
});`
```

Comment: What DatePicker plugin are you using, jQuery UI?